# Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: places.id (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, expo

I am using SQLite, but when I run the code, error comes out "NOT NULL constraint failed: places.id (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)", can someone help me?

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";

const db = SQLite.openDatabase("places.db");

export const init = () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, title TEXT NOT NULL, imageUri TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL, lat REAL NOT NULL, lng REAL NOT NULL);",
        [],
        () => {
          resolve();
        },
        (_, err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  });
  return promise;
};

export const insertPlace = (title, imageUri, address, lat, lng) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `INSERT INTO places (title, imageUri, address, lat, lng) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`,
        [title, imageUri, address, lat, lng],
        (_, result) => {
          resolve(result);
        },
        (_, err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  });
  return promise;
};
```

Comment: make sure the Id in your Places table is an identity field, so that it autofills when you Insert.  If you don't, you will have to define the Id yourself

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this error by deleting the expo go app on my simulator / actual device and then running the app again